# UK - EEA Family permit refusal for mother due not enough dependency

Tags: united-kingdom

I am a German citizen living in the UK with a granted settlement status. My mother lives in Germany and we went to Calais/France border to get interviewed there and the visa stamp as it is quicker and my lawyer told me to do it that way.

I have applied for an EEA family permit for my mother as an dependent direct family member of an EEA national (me) to accompany me in the United Kingdom.

Unfortunately we got refused and the reason was: „there was not enough dependency proved“.

I lived with my mother before I moved out and I always gave her cash in hand (for rent and her expenses) because why would I transfer money to someone I live with if I can just give it to them cash. She always takes out the money anyways. So there is no way to provide proof of that.

I said that I am self sufficient and also due to corona there was not enough work for me and I therefore did not have enough income (around 1,2k monthly usually I get over 2K) but I was still sending her money after I moved out. I was sending money for over 7 months but the home office said it’s not enough dependency.

So we applied AGAIN for an EEA Family permit but online this time and with the same documents I proved in Calais/France border.
We went to the visa application center in Germany and after the decision came, we received the same refusal. Again saying not enough dependency provided.

Here is the refusal:

*In assessing your individual application, it has not been necessary to interview you, but I have taken account of:*

*-the personal circumstances as declared by you on your application form,
-your passport,
-your family circumstances and
-the supporting documents you provided.*

*I have used all the information provided by you to determine if the requirements of the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016 have been met.* *In reaching my decision, which has been made on the balance of probabilities, I note the following points:*

**The Decision**

*You state that your sponsor is a German national.
You have provided evidence that your
sponsor holds a German passport.*

*I acknowledge all the supporting documents you have provided including the letter from your lawyer.*

*I note that this letter states, and is corroborated by the stamps in your passport, that you were refused entry to the UK through Calais on the XX.XX.XXXX.* *It also states the Immigration Officer made an incorrect assessment of your relationship and dependency on your sponsor, however they have failed to fully explain what constituted an incorrect decision, given they themselves state you were given ample time to provide all the appropriate information at the point of entry.*
*They stated that you were questioned intensely with an interpreter which is contrary to your best interests, however given you speak a language other than English the Officers are only able to make an assessment of your circumstances once they are able to obtain all the information.* *It is your responsibility to demonstrate that you meet the regulations in order to qualify for entry to the UK.*

*You state that you are financially reliant on your sponsor to meet your essential living needs. Additionally, you state that you receive £150 monthly from your sponsor. For this office to establish your dependency, we must be satisfied that you require financial support from your EEA national sponsor to meet your essential living needs.*
*In support of this, you have provided 4 money transfer remittance receipts dated between 19  September 2020 and 14 December 2020 to you, though there is nothing to show who the funds have been sent from.*
*I also note you have provided a bank statement in your sponsor’s name from XXXXXX Bank – account ending  XXX. I note the transactions in this account however I am unable to equate any of the funds to you and your support.* *I note you have also provided a tenancy agreement in your name and that of your sponsor as well as letters to you both with that address, however the tenancy agreement is undated and so I am unable to establish when this was signed and when it relates to, and if it genuinely relates to Accommodation you share.* *You state your sponsor is self-sufficient however there is insufficient evidence to demonstrate her circumstances and what funds she has.* *Given the information provided I am not satisfied she has the means to support you as well as herself. Further to this there is nothing to show that your sponsor is the one providing this accommodation.* *I note hat on previous applications you have made to travel to the UK you have mentioned numerous other family members who reside there which also causes me to question whether you are reliant on this sponsor for your essential living needs or if you are reliant on others.*

*This office would expect to see evidence which fully details yours and your family’s circumstances. Your income, expenditure and evidence of your financial position which would prove that without the financial support of your sponsor your essential living needs could not be met. The fact of transferring money is not evidence that it is needed by the recipient.* *Unfortunately, this limited amount of evidence does not prove that you are financially dependent on your sponsor.*

*IN addition to the above you state you met the requirements because you both hold European Health Insurance cards, however the regulations state that these are only valid for a temporary stay in the UK.* *Your application states that you intend to settle and so the Immigration Officer would have noted that you had insufficient insurance for your settlement in the UK given your sponsor is stated to be self-sufficient. Given this and the above there is a concern that you will become a burden on the public funds system of the United Kingdom.*

*On the evidence submitted in support of your application and on the balance of probability I am not satisfied you are related as claimed, or dependent on your sponsor.*

*I am therefore not satisfied that you are a dependent direct family member in accordance with Regulation(s) 7(1) of the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016.*

*I therefore refuse your EEA Family Permit application because I am not satisfied that you meet all of the requirements of regulation 12 (see ECGs EUN2.23) of the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016.*

the funny thing is:

1. I sent her more than 150€ a month
2. I was going to Germany visiting her every 1-2 months and was giving her cash in hand again
3. I have NHS in the UK (only my mom has insurance in Germany)
4. I can clearly support myself with the income I have
5. And my mother too
6. If I wasn’t able to support myself I would be claiming benefits right now which I am not
7. the immigration rules/law says I refer to the Home Office Guidance on “EU Settlement Scheme: EU, other EEA and Swiss Citizens and their family member” (Version 7.0) which states: Their dependency on the relevant EEA citizen (or qualifying British citizen) or on the spouse or civil partner is assumed and the Applicant is not required to provide evidence of this.”

So technically evidence of dependency is not required, right? Please let me know if I’m wrong!

Comment: The EEA Family Permit has been discontinued.  I presume that you are actually applying for an EU Settlement Scheme Family Permit; is that correct?  Also, could you edit the question to add a link to the document you're referring to in point 7?  That way we can be certain that we are speaking about the same document (but the text you quote is almost certainly not applicable to parents; it should apply to spouses and minor children or something like that).

Comment: Also, is your mother planning to settle in the UK? Is she a German citizen?

Comment: The latest version (11) can be downloaded here:  [EU Settlement Scheme caseworker guidance - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eu-settlement-scheme-caseworker-guidance). See page 108: **Dependent parent** *‘Dependent’ means that, as demonstrated by relevant financial, medical or other documentary evidence:...*

Comment: @phoog I know the EEA Family permit has been discontinued. We applied before 31.21.2020. Do you think I should appeal this or is there any other visa I can apply for? Also my sister is 14 years old and a British citizen but she lives with my mother in Germany. What if she moves to the UK to live with me. Are there any chances of my mother being able to come here over her? Since she’s going to start school here and doesn’t need to show proof of work or anything. And yes my mother wanted to settle/live here with me but she is not a German citizen. If she would’ve been a German, easy - no visa.

Comment: @Caliya it's probably better to apply for an EUSS family permit (that is, a new application).  There are two reasons.  First, you cannot introduce new evidence in an appeal; the application failed because of a lack of evidence; and therefore the refusal is likely to be sustained on appeal.  Second, even if the appeal were successful, an EEA family permit is now useless.

Comment: @phoog what is the difference between the family permit and the EUSS? Please let me know

Comment: @phoog also what about the question i asked about my younger sister? She is a British citizen and is turning 14 years old soon. But she lives with my mother in Germany. What if she moves to the UK to live with me. Are there any chances of my mother being able to come here over her? Since she’s going to start school here and doesn’t need to show proof of work or anything.

Comment: @markJohnson also what is meant with: other documentary evidence (of dependency)

Comment: @Caliya the EUSS family permit is issued to family of EU Settlement Scheme participants.  The EEA family permit was issued under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations, which are no longer in force.

Comment: @Caliya is your mother your sister's primary caregiver?

Comment: @phoog: I just saw this now..

„Since your mother is not a dependent child or grandchild, the first bullet point does not apply. Since you are not under 18, the second bullet point does not apply. Therefore, your mother will not have to show evidence of her dependency“

So that means if I apply for the EUSS I would not need to prove any kind of dependency AND ALSO my mother would be able to come to the UK just like that?

If the answer is yes then I won’t need my sister then.

And regards your question: „ is your mother your sister's primary caregiver?“ — Yes, she is.

Answer (score 1):

> 7. the immigration rules/law says I refer to the Home Office Guidance on “EU Settlement Scheme: EU, other EEA and Swiss Citizens and their family member” (Version 7.0) which states: Their dependency on the relevant EEA citizen (or qualifying British citizen) or on the spouse or civil partner is assumed and the Applicant is not required to provide evidence of this.”

The guidance quoted here applies to EU Settlement Scheme family permits, but the application that was refused was for an EEA family permit.  The quoted guidance is therefore not relevant to that application.  But it seems that it would be relevant to a fresh application for an EUSS family permit.  See the [relevant government page](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit):

> You’ll also have to show that you are dependent on [your EU family member who has lived in the UK since before December 31, 2020] if:
>
> - you’re over 21 and a dependent child or grandchild of your family member
> - your family member is under 18 and you’re their dependent parent or grandparent

Since your mother is not a dependent child or grandchild, the first bullet point does not apply.  Since you are not under 18, the second bullet point does not apply.  Therefore, your mother will not have to show evidence of her dependency.

Comment: Also my lawyer said we have to get the family permit first so that when she comes after we can apply for the EUSS. Is that correct too?

Comment: I just saw this now..

„Since your mother is not a dependent child or grandchild, the first bullet point does not apply. Since you are not under 18, the second bullet point does not apply. Therefore, your mother will not have to show evidence of her dependency“

So that means if I apply for the EUSS I would not need to prove any kind of dependency AND ALSO my mother would be able to come to the UK just like that?

If the answer is yes then I won’t need my sister then.

And regards your question: „ is your mother your sister's primary caregiver?“ — Yes, she is.

Comment: My lawyers trainee advised me BEFORE I SPOKE TO MY LAWYER that I shouldn’t appeal and apply for EUSS instead. 

Today I spoke to him and he telling me that we should appeal instead of applying to the EUSS... what do you think about that? what should I do?

You also haven’t replied back to the message I sent before.

Comment: You were basically trying to claim that your mother won’t survive in Germany on her own and therefore has to move to the UK to live with you. So she has no income, no pension, no state benefits, no other children? Seriously? Four months ago your mother could have moved to the UK without any problems whatsoever, she would have pre-settled status now and would get settled status end of 2025. Without any lawyer.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah that’s what my lawyer told me to do .. now I feel like he just wasted my time and money after reading what you just said. 

And how could’ve it been possible 4 months ago and without any lawyer?  

And are you saying it’s impossible now? If yes why? 
Please let me know

Comment: 4 months ago EU citizens could just move to the UK, no questions asked. Until Dec 31st 2021. Then apply for pre-settled status.

Comment: @Caliya as far as I understand it there is no basis for appeal and, because of the change in the law on 1/1/2021 a successful appeal would not actually be helpful.  I think that you are right to be skeptical of this lawyer.  Note that you can also do both: an application for an EUSS FP should not prevent you from appealing.  Perhaps you should apply for the EUSS FP and then decide whether to appeal after you get the decision.

Comment: @Caliya If you want continued legal assistance try to find out whether the lawyer is in good standing.  Look for other clients of the lawyer to see what their experiences were. Visit https://www.freemovement.org.uk/, especially the "legal advice" section at the bottom of the home page.

Comment: @Caliya for some reason I did not see the notification for your message of two days ago.  To reply to the messages of April 14: "my lawyer said we have to get the family permit first so that when she comes after we can apply for the EUSS": that is confusing.  You must get an EUSS family permit before getting a residence permit through the EUSS.  But remember that the earlier application was for an EEA family permit (not an EUSS family permit), which no longer exists, so a successful appeal of that refusal is useless. Maybe the lawyer didn't realize that it was an EEA FP application.

Comment: @Caliya "So that means if I apply for the EUSS I would not need to prove any kind of dependency AND ALSO my mother would be able to come to the UK just like that?" I think that's what it means, yes.  I find it surprising that the UK assumes that the claim of dependence is true, but they say so in more than one place, so it is unlikely to be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @gnasher729 it's not necessary to prove that the dependent parent cannot survive in another place on her own. It is sufficient to prove dependence. The right to be joined by one's family is not limited to situations in which the family depends on exercising that right.  Furthermore, the EEA family permit application was made before 31 December 2020 (as it must have been), so Caliya's mother must not be an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen, and it's therefore not true that "four months ago [she] could have moved to the UK without any problems whatsoever."

Comment: @phoog thanks for letting me know. I was wondering why you weren’t replying. And I have to mention, my mother is not a EU Citizen only I have the German Citizenship. I am living in the UK and have also been granted the EUSS pre settle status. 
If that help in anyway

Comment: @phoog I spoke to my lawyer the other day about if I should Appeal or not. He said we should Appel because he said they have decided unlawfully but then he has no guarantee that it would be successfull. Which makes me think: if they handled unlawfully how would it not be successful? He also said I will have to pay for a barrister if they say a hearing has to be taken place. But we can appeal AND apply for the EUSS at the same time and incase the EUSS application is successful we can leave the Appeal. What do you think about that and what would you suggest me to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123363/discussion-between-caliya-and-phoog).

Comment: @phoog can you tell me what the difference is between the EEA family permit and the EUSS family permit

Comment: And also the EUSS